# Portable soil and compost testing kit

Tags: vegetables, soil, compost, soil-test

I am growing vegetables. I need soil and compost testing kits for soil Ph, soil EC and compost nutrients test.

Can anyone suggest which instruments will be good and have a reasonable price?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have enough points to comment.  I know this isn't the answer you're looking for but I've always used hanna pens. hannainst.com

Look around their website and see what they have that would suit you and is in your price range.

Answer (score 2):

I picked up a decent soil test kit at a big box store and it seemed to work fine for me. Got a great crop that year too. [Link to kit](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Ferry-Morse-40-Test-Soil-Test-Kit-920/202819850#.UtdrmbSxGtU)